# Using google oAuth2 to collect gmail email from java app

Tags: java, gmail, google-oauth

I have a web base email client that uses a java app to connect to IMAP and POP3 servers to download email. There is an issue that if a user usually logs in form the US that the java app will not have access to collect emails until that user logs in from the same county the java app is running.

I was told to overcome this to use google oAuth in order for the account user to give permission to my app to collect emails. Is this correct? Once this has been accomplished I would also like to the the API to import contacts, but for now authorization/authentication is sufficient.

The problem I am facing is that after trying to make heads a or tails of the google oAuth api documentation im really confused and did not yet manage to make a working example. Documentation often has links to a depreciated API and there is no example with a dowload link to both the API needed and exaple source code, as a result I think im using incorrect libraries for my examples.

Its also not clear to me what/how to accomplish what is needed do I use client authentication via javascript to create a popup whereby the user grants access?

Or do I use installed app client with a token and secret, this is what I tried but the 'command line' example I tried requires Java EE and this is a native app so I dont see why and I dont want to import all Java EE libraries to my small email downloader app.

Where can I find more intuitive documentation and working examples on this?

Answer (score 0):

If you stay away from OpenID 2 and OAuth 1, I think the docs are pretty orderly these days.  The best place to start is https://developers.google.com/accounts/docs/OAuth2